# ADB command exec-out in subprocess.Popen() not working

Tags: python, subprocess, adb

I am trying to pull a screenshot from an ADB device connected from python.

Instead of capturing and pulling it from the device which works well, I tried to use exec-out

```
adb exec-out screencap -p > D:\\Screenshot.png
```

This works from command prompt but when I try this from python subprocess, screenshot is not fetched

```
 args = ['adb','exec-out','screencap','-p','>','D:\\Screenshot.png']
 cmdp = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

 self.__output, self.__error = cmdp.communicate()
 retcode = cmdp.wait()
```

The code executes without any error but the screenshot is not pulled.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with shell=True for subprocess.Popen.

Comment: it works.... :)

Comment: @Azeeb - can you post the working code?

Comment: subprocess.run(['adb', 'exec-out', 'screencap', '-p', '>', 'screen.png'],shell=True)